# Where is `personal dictionary` for `ispell` located?

Tags: microsoft-windows, hunspell

`C-h v ispell-personal-dictionary` shows `nil`. Its docstring says:

```
Documentation:
File name of your personal spelling dictionary, or nil.
If nil, the default personal dictionary for your spelling checker is used.
```

My spellchecker is hunpsell, installed in `C:\Hunspell`, Windows 10. Emacs finds it and performs spellcheck without issues.

Can't find any personal dic in its folder and subfolders.

Edit: the first comment gives a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653754/emacs-on-win32-with-hunspell-personal-dictionary-does-not-get-saved), which explains where the default location is.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653754/emacs-on-win32-with-hunspell-personal-dictionary-does-not-get-saved) answer your question?

Comment: Excellent pointer! Will try. Meanwhile,  irrespective of any value of ‘ispell-personal-dictionary’, Emacs somehow saves the words I add to personal dictionary with ‘i’ key and doesn’t flag these next time it checks the same words.

Comment: Well, it seems by default $HOME is used to to write personal dics into. I guess I can close this question. Edit: unless I can modify it a bit?

Comment: It's better not to edit the question in order to ask a different question: you should edit it only to add additiona information.  You can answer your own question and accept it (you probably should in this case). But nobody will see the modified question about Dropbox, so it's better to ask a new question, with a title that more accurately reflects the new question you want to ask.

Answer (score 2):

The link in the first comment answered the question.

From the man page:

```
-p dict

Set path of personal dictionary. Default is $HOME/.hunspell_default. Setting -d or the DICTIONARY environmental variable, personal dictionary will be $HOME/.hunspell_dicname
```

This answers where hunspell stores personal dics. ‘ispell’ works with other backends (‘aspell’, ‘enchant’) and things are different there.

Comment: `$HOME` is not a variable set by default in Windows. When it's not set, I suppose the folder used is the one in which Emacs is started?

Comment: $HOME seems to be equal to %USERPROFILE% on my system. I see ispell creating personal dics there, not in Emacs’ start/working dir.

Comment: it could be under `~/.aspell.en.pws` too

Answer (score 0):

You can find it at C:\users\username\hunspell_default